# Google App Engine NDB keyproperty counter

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I have a model for user to store their bookmarks. What is the best way to get the total number of bookmarks, should I create a field to store the number of total or aggregrate it when user retrieve the data ?

```
class UserBookMarks(Model):
    class Meta:
        behaviors = (searchable.Searchable,)
        search_exclude=('created')

    user= ndb.KeyProperty(kind=User, repeated=False)
    items = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=ItemList, repeated=True)
    created = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counting or aggregating in the Datastore is inefficient.  Therefore create a field to store the total.  If a counter needs to be updated more than a few times per second (unlikely with user bookmarks) you would need to resort to sharded counters.

Comment: Reference to the doc on sharded counters: https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters